# What is correct of SCP command on Ubuntu Hardy

Tags: scp

If the use the following scp command then I get an error:

scp -P 22 username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: /home/username/public_html/* ./

The error I get is:

stdin: is not a tty
scp: .: not a regular file

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the space after the IP address of the remote machine:

```
scp -P 22 username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/username/public_html/* ./
```

Comment: Just to calrify, I only want to copy everything in public_html folder including all sub-directories and files.

Is this the right command for it?

Comment: I am getting the error "stdin: is not a tty" and then it copies some files from public_html folder and then stops.It does not copy any sub-folders.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy everything under public_html, this would be correct way to do it:

scp **-r** -P 22 username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/username/public_html .

-r recurses through the subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Think of scp the same way you think of cp. cp can't copy directions unless you specify some recursion for it to grab every folder and file within the said folder. If you want to copy a folder, you'd run ***cp -r folder/ destination/***. scp is the same. You'll need to run ***scp -r user@host:/path/to/folder destination/***

As a note, when using the default port for SSH (22) you don't need to specify it in the scp command.